# How can i tell if a MySQL query returned nothing in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, null

I'm using PHP5 and MySQL. I'm using `mysql_...()` functions.

Comment: Which library are you using to access MySQL.  There's at least 3, including the mysql_ functions, mysqli_, and PDO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query_identifier) == 0)
  echo "Query returned 0 rows";
```

Additionally, mysql_query() returns `false` in case of an error.

[Manual: MySQL functions in PHP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)

Comment: mysql_query() isn't returning false for some reason, but I'm limiting the query with a WHERE clause on a test query and I'm sure that the data won't match the query.

Comment: @Moshe, mysql_query only returns false when there is an _error_. If your WHERE clause is not matching any rows then you will, unsurprisingly, have no results.. not an error though.

Comment: @Moshe: If you want to count results, then yes. I just mentioned the `false` case because it is important to provide for that as well.

Comment: It depends on your code. `mysql_num_rows()` returns the number of result rows - if it returns 0, then the result is empty. BUT you may also just want to read the result and do nothing if no result row arrives, e.g. `while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC) ) { do_something_with_row($row); }`. What more do you need or want?

Comment: I mean, in most cases you do not need to call `mysql_num_rows()`, because when you READ the result, you will know that the result is empty!

Comment: Depends what you want to do. If you want to do a "this table is empty." output, you may need to count them.

Comment: @Moshe: Yes. As Pekka and frunsi have pointed out, `mysql_num_rows()` will tell you how many rows are in your result. If it returns 0, then your result set is empty. frunsi's approach above is also correct, though, mysql_num_rows can be useful in other cases as well, e.g. displaying the number of results in addition to the results themselves without keeping a running count of the results.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. (If you believe in that sort of thing.)  My psuedocode: *if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){//do something}else{echo 'nothing doing';}*

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mysqli_ functions, you can call [$stmt->num_rows()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).  But only after calling $stmt->store_result() to ensure all the rows have been returned.

Comment: @Kibbee: you might as well delete this. the OP pointed out that he is using the mysql_ functions in an edit 6~7 minutes prior to your answer.